# C# calling function in class from other namespace

Tags: c#, function, class, methods

I have this function in a class:

```
        public void CreateWeapon()
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(0, weaponNames.Length);

        newWeapon = new BaseWeapon();

        newWeapon.ItemName = weaponNames[x];
        newWeapon.Strength = rnd.Next(0, 5);
        newWeapon.Vitality = rnd.Next(0, 5);
        newWeapon.Intelligence = rnd.Next(0, 5);

        ChooseWeaponType();

    }
```

It lies in the namespace RPG_GUI.Items

Since my "Form1.cs" is lying in RPG_GUI I can not call the function although it's a public one.

I'm trying it with this command:

```
RPG_GUI.Items.CreateNewWeapon
```

CreateNewWeapon.cs is the name of the separate class file. But I can't call the function anywhere else, how may i fix that?

Comment: Ýou could make it `static`

Comment: You need an instance of the class that `CreateWeapon()` belongs to. Alternatively you could make it a static method have it `return newWeapon;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Method you have provided is not declared static, so to invoke it you would need to declare an instance of the class to which `CreateNewWeapon` belongs (that class was not included in your code snippet).

Alternatively change your method declaration to: `public static void CreateWeapon()`

Comment: Declaring an instance of that class .. Sometimes it's hard to think inside the box. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the class first or make the fuction static